# Onclick reload the div only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(window).load(function() {      
  $("#Button").click(function() {
    alert('clicked')
    $("#div").load(" #div > *");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="Button" class="btn btn-warning">Refresh</button>
<div class="col-md-3" id="div">

  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>

  </div>
</div>
```

Heres the code where am trying to `reload` the div when I `click` the Refresh `button`, nothing is happening, as I am a learner of jQuery and JS am not having much knowledge about this.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/hztzketh/) link

Thanks

## zeasts

Comment: use like this $("#MyButton").click(function() , you dont have a Button id in your html

Comment: I think Its there @Deep

Comment: <button id="MyButton" class="btn btn-warning">Refresh</button>

Comment: sorry, I modified and forgot to update, will update now... Thx

Comment: Fiidle https://jsfiddle.net/hztzketh/5/

You might have user older version ( <= 1.9)

Comment: yup, its working in Fiddle there, but in my local not working :( @DineshPatra

Comment: check, I have answered a html+jquery. Its working.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery version 3 the function load and the event onload are handled differently.

So in your code you need to write:

```
$(window).on('load', function (e) {
```

For details take a look to [jQuery 3.0](https://blog.jquery.com/2015/07/13/jquery-3-0-and-jquery-compat-3-0-alpha-versions-released/):

> Removed deprecated event aliases
>
> .load, .unload, and .error, deprecated since jQuery 1.8, are no more. Use .on() to register listeners.
>
> https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2286

Because Bootstrap v3 is not compatible with jQuery v3 (refer to [bootstrap issues 16834](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834)) I changed to jQuery 1.x in my snippet.

My snippet:

```js
$(window).on('load', function (e) {
  $('#MyButton').on('click', function (e) {
    alert('clicked')
    $("#div").load(" #div > *");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="MyButton" class="btn btn-warning">Refresh</button>
<div class="col-md-3" id="div">

    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not working, but in the console its firing the error as `jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load.(html link) Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain For bootstrap 3.3.6 you cannot use jQuery 3.x. So I updated my snippet to jQuery 1.x. Try now and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The load method requests some content from the server and places it in the div that you call it on.
An example of its use could be:

```
$("#IdOfElementToPutContentIn").load("urlToGrabDataFrom")
```

Look at the API to understand this better:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your local machine. Its working in my browser

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button id="MyButton" class="btn btn-warning">Refresh</button>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="div">

            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load', function (e) {
            $('#MyButton').on('click', function (e) {
                alert('clicked')
                $("#div").load(" #div > *");
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```